# lvalue required as left operand of assignment 2

Tags: c++, syntax-error

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int g1, m1, s1, g2, m2, s2, x, y, z;
    cin >> g1 >> m1 >> s1 >> g2 >> m2 >> s2;
    x=g1+g2;
    y=m1+m2;
    z=s1+s2;
    if(m1+m2>59) x+1 && y=y-60;
    if(s1+s2>59) y+1 && z=z-60;
    cout << x << y << z;
}
```

I'm new to c++ and don't know how to fix it, can someone help me?

Comment: I know there is an answer to this question. But could you explain that you want `x+1 && y=y-60;` to do.  Even `x+1 && (y=y-60);` as in the answer is an unusual expression.

Comment: Why would anyone want to write obscure code like this? Just break it up into multiple expressions: `if ((m1+m2)>59) { x+=1; y-=60; } if ((s1+s2)>59) { y+=1; z-=60; }`

Comment: i need to calculate degrees, minutes and seconds of an angle, and if there are more than 60 minutes this should add to degrees 1 and decrease value of minutes by 60

Comment: `x + 1` and `y + 1` are temporaries which are not assigned to anything in your scenario. did you mean `x += 1`/`y += 1` instead?

Comment: @zxcmaxik Then what you want is `{ ++x; y -= 60; }` and similar for the other if test.

Comment: can you explain what does ++x do?

Comment: it increments `x` by one

Comment: Can you guys help to fix the problem? I need the value of the minutes and seconds not to be greater than 59, and if it is greater than 2 or 3 times, to add 1, 2, 3 or as much as necessary to the minutes or degrees

Comment: @zxcmaxik that should be asked in another question.  This question has been answered and changing/modifying the question would invalidate the answer.

Comment: Ok, thank you guys very much for providing help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that assignment operator `=` [has the lowest precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) in your expressions:

> ```cpp
> if(m1+m2>59) x+1 && y=y-60;
> if(s1+s2>59) y+1 && z=z-60;
> ```

Thus, the compiler sees the expressions like this:

```cpp
(x + 1 && y) = (y - 60);
(y + 1 && z) = (z - 60);
```

And the result of `(x + 1 && y)` and `(y + 1 && z)` cannot be assigned, because it's an rvalue.

Instead you probably want the assignment to take place prior to evaluating result of `&&`:

```cpp
if(m1 + m2 > 59) x + 1 && (y = y - 60);
if(s1 + s2 > 59) y + 1 && (z = z - 60);
```

Comment: OP has clarified what the expression should be doing. You might want to update the answer.

Comment: @RichardCritten in order to meet the requirements OP provided, I'll have to rewrite this expression completely, as it's neither correct to increment `x`/`y` by one, nor decrement `y`/`z` by 60. The input can be any value, not limited to range of 60 seconds/minutes. Thus the answer then will be irrelevant to original question. As you suggested, OP may want to ask another question to sort this part properly